# c# How to prevent data from being lost when using next and previous button?

Tags: c#

I have form 1 with next button and form 2 with previous button. I was on form 2 then went back to form 1 using the previous button, but when I click the next button from form 1, my data on form 2 is gone. How do I keep that data?

This my code:

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    staticVar = this;
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Comment: `var form2 = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form2>().FirstOrDefault(); if (form2 is null) { form2 = new Form2(); } form2.Show();`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a windows form already exists, open it if it does, creates a new one if it doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34792307/how-to-check-if-a-windows-form-already-exists-open-it-if-it-does-creates-a-new)

Comment: Finally.. tq so much for the code sir..